# Gradle invoke task from maven plugin from own task

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I have multi-modular project. I imported maven plugin to make it possible upload api and util jars on nexus.

here code of build.gradle

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.1'
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea';
    apply plugin: 'java';
    apply plugin: 'maven';
    def propFile = file('gradle.properties')
    def Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream('gradle.properties'))
    sourceCompatibility = props['SOURCE_COMPATIBILITY'];
    targetCompatibility = props['TARGET_COMPATIBILITY'];
    group = props['GROUP']
}

subprojects {
    compileJava.options.encoding = 'utf-8'

    propFile = file('gradle.properties')
    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(project.name + '/gradle.properties'))
    ver = props['VERSION']
    rel = props['RELEASE']
    rev = props['REVISION']

    archivesBaseName = props['ARCHIVES_BASE_NAME']
    version = ver + '.' + rel + '.' + rev

    task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from sourceSets.main.allSource
    }

    artifacts {
        archives sourcesJar
    }

    uploadArchives {
        repositories {

            mavenDeployer {
                propFile = file('gradle.properties')
                props = new Properties()
                props.load(new FileInputStream('gradle.properties'))
                if (project.hasProperty('local')) {
                    repository(url: "$System.env.M2_LOCAL")
                    if (project.getProperties().get("v")) {
                        pom.version = project.getProperties().get("v")
                    } else {
                        if (project.hasProperty("iv")) {
                            switch (project.getProperties().get("iv").toString().toLowerCase()) {
                                case 'ver' :
                                    props['VERSION'] = (ver.toInteger() + 1).toString();
                                    props['RELEASE'] = "0";
                                    props['REVISION'] = "0";
                                    break
                                case 'rel' :
                                    props['RELEASE'] = (rel.toInteger() + 1).toString();
                                    props['REVISION'] = "0";
                                    break
                                default :
                                    props['REVISION'] = (rev.toInteger() + 1).toString();
                            }
                        } else {
                            props['REVISION'] = (rev.toInteger() + 1).toString()
                        }
                        pom.version = props['VERSION'] + '.' + props['RELEASE'] + '.' + props['REVISION']
                        pom.version = props['VERSION'] + '.' + props['RELEASE'] + '.' + props['REVISION']
                        props.store(propFile.newWriter(), null)
                    }
                } else {
                    repository(url: "http://maven.wideup.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/") {
                        authentication(userName: 'admin', password: project.getProperties().get("password"))
                    }
                    if (project.getProperties().get("v")) {
                        pom.version = project.getProperties().get("v")
                    } else {
                        if (project.hasProperty("iv")) {
                            switch (project.getProperties().get("iv").toString().toLowerCase()) {
                                case 'ver' :
                                    props['VERSION'] = (ver.toInteger() + 1).toString();
                                    props['RELEASE'] = "0";
                                    props['REVISION'] = "0";
                                    break
                                case 'rel' :
                                    props['RELEASE'] = (rel.toInteger() + 1).toString();
                                    props['REVISION'] = "0";
                                    break
                                default :
                                    props['REVISION'] = (rev.toInteger() + 1).toString();
                            }
                        } else {
                            props['REVISION'] = (rev.toInteger() + 1).toString()
                        }
                        pom.version = props['VERSION'] + '.' + props['RELEASE'] + '.' + props['REVISION']
                        props.store(propFile.newWriter(), null)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task localUpload << {
        println maven
    }


    configurations {
        provided
    }

    idea.module {
        scopes.PROVIDED.plus += configurations.provided
    }

    repositories {

        mavenLocal();

        maven {
            url 'http://maven.wideup.net/nexus/content/groups/public/'
        }

    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            compileClasspath += configurations.provided
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate { prj ->
        def isEar = prj.plugins.hasPlugin('ear')
        if (isEar) {
            configure(prj) {
                dependencies {


                }
                if (ext.properties.containsKey('webModules')) {
                    deploymentDescriptor {
                        ext.properties.webModules.each {
                            webModule(dependencies.project(path: it.key).name + '-' + project.version + ".war", it.value)
                        }
                    }
                }


            }

            task api(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
                archiveName = project(':comm.api').name + '-' + version + '.' + extension
                from project(':comm.api').sourceSets.main.output
            }

            task sourcesApi(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
                archiveName = project(':comm.api').name + '-' + version + '-sources.' + extension
                from project(':comm.api').sourceSets.main.allSource
            }

        } else {
            configure(prj) {
                dependencies {


                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now I can simply call from the terminal comand like this:

```
gradlew :comm.api:upload -Ppassword=somepassword
```

it isn't so easy to use evrytime in this maner.
To simplify I created task localUpload

I need that while i simply call

```
gradlew :comm:api:localUpload
```

it finds password for repository somewhere in local files and call the method **upload** passing password as parameter.

How can I invoke :comm.api:upload -Ppassword=pass from task localUpload?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: How can i invoke gradlew :comm.api:upload -Ppassword=somepassword
when i call gradlew :comm.api:localUpload;